# Django database objects not showing on the template

Tags: django

Am i am rendering django objects using django_tables and the for loop iteration but both methods aren't working

i am trying to render objects saved in the database by a modelform. My first approach i used the django_tables2 which returned non-type object.

currently i have used the for loop to iterate through the objects but the object values are not being displayed. what intrigues me is that all rows are being returned with no data. kindly help.

models.py

```
class Issuekeys(models.Model):
    keynumber=models.CharField(max_length=10);
    workorder=models.CharField(max_length=50);
    contrator=models.CharField(max_length=50);
    contrator_contact=models.IntegerField();
    assigned_name=models.CharField(max_length=50);
    assigned_ID=models.IntegerField();
    assigned_contact=models.IntegerField();
    date_to_return=models.DateField();

    class Meta:
        managed=False
        db_table='ieng_mis_issuekeys'
```

views.py

```
def issuetable(request):
     query_set=zip(Issuekeys.objects.all())
     context={'query_set': query_set}
     return render(request, 'keymanager.html',context)
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^keymanager$', views.issuetable,name='keymanager'),
```

keymanager.html

```
<div class="bg-light" style="margin-top: 1em; margin-left: 1mm">
    <table class="table table-hover">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Key Number</th>
            <th scope="col">Work Order</th>
            <th scope="col">Contractor</th>
            <th scope="col">Assignee Name</th>
            <th scope="col">Assignee Contact</th>
            <th scope="col">Date issued</th>
        </tr>
        {% for key in query_set %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{key.keynumber}}</td>
            <td>{{key.workorder}}</td>
            <td>{{key.contractor}}</td>
            <td>{{key.assigned_name}}</td>
            <td>{{key.assigned_contract}}</td>
            <td>{{key.date_to_return}}</td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

output

Comment: What is `zip` supposed to do there? Can you remove it and try again?

Comment: thanks alot. i thought it was useful in making the queryset iterable. what a mistake,it  working well now.

Comment: Querysets are iterables, and although `zip` is a very useful built-in function, it is not used for making _something_ iterable anyway.

Answer (score -1):

```
In views.py, you just have to remove zip function, only need to query like this - IssueKeys.objects.all().

zip function returns the list of tuple like this [(<Issuekeys:somevalue>),(<Issuekeys:somevalue>)], where the tuple contains the model object, But In template, you should return the list of model object like this :- [<Issuekeys:somevalue>, <Issuekeys:somevalue>]

So when you iterate over the list in template, you will get the model object in the list directly and you can access the model class attributes.

    def issuetable(request):
         query_set=Issuekeys.objects.all()
         context={'query_set': query_set}
         return render(request, 'keymanager.html',context)
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it